# how to upload local file with progress bar in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to upload a file from an application with a progress bar, but I don't know how to do it. I use coil but here it turns out to show progress with a percentage.

```
Image(
                painter = rememberImagePainter(
                    data = getContentActivityResult.uri,
                    builder = {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(50.dp)
                        ) {
                            placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                        }
                        if (file != null) {
                            getFile(getContentActivityResult)
                        }

                        this.listener(
                            onError = { imageRequest, throwable ->
                                throwable.message
                            },
                            onStart = {
                                Log.e("TAG", "ProgressUI: start load image")
                            },
                            onSuccess = { imageRequest, metaData ->
                                Log.e("TAG", "ProgressUI: ${metaData.dataSource.name}")
                            },
                            onCancel = {
                                Log.e("TAG", "ProgressUI: cancel file")
                            },

                            )
                    },

                    ),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                contentDescription = "ads-photo",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            )
```